# What does 拜 mean in 拜在俄做生意的中国有钱人所赐，他们的入境手续都不合法?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word

In the following sentence over [知乎](https://www.zhihu.com/question/28201101/answer/40711457):

> 最后，特别特别重要的提示！！！出门的时候记得带上护照，遇到警察，在他没有发现你之前躲开他！俄罗斯的警察待遇非常低，所以几乎90%的警察都会勒索外国人，尤其是中国人（**拜**在俄做生意的中国有钱人所赐，他们的入境手续都不合法，所以一查就给钱，一查就给钱，一来二去警察都知道中国人好给钱了），当然如果你懂语言且签证合法的话，也可以和他们沟通，一般遇到这样的，警察也不敢太过分，但总而言之还是躲着他们好。

According to Pleco, I found out that 拜 can work as the following:

> POLITE [used before a verb to show respect]

That might make sense in this context. But I have never seen that kind of usage of 拜 and I'm not sure if it is correct.

Or does 拜 here mean anything others?

Comment: Just to augment a bit: 拜Xxx所赐 is almost ALWAYS used sarcastically or ironically. I should not say it's impossible , but its literal meaning is not used, in practice. Maybe, it's not proper to use it to mean you are really grateful for one's help. For example, 拜你所赐，我考试通过了！ this sentence sounds strange, because if you say 拜你所赐，I would expect you say something negative, but instead you say a positive thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`拜X所賜, Y` is a standard expression which means *Y happens, thanks to X* or *if it weren't for X, Y wouldn't have happened*. It may also carry all the sarcasm or irony contained in the English version. If you want to decompose the structure, it literally means `acknowledging the bestowed/conferred upon X, this causes Y`.

> 拜在俄做生意的中國有錢人所賜，他們的入境手續都不合法，所以一查就給錢，一查就給錢，一來二去警察都知道中國人好給錢了
>
> Thanks to the wealthy Chinese people doing business in Russia, who enter the country without following proper procedures and underhandedly pay the inspection/police officers every time they get checked, all the police officers [*who are inside this shady bribery business*] now know [or more logically, *are now under the impression*] that Chinese people love giving bribes.

Answer (score 1):

"拜"  means "thanks to/ all because of" in this context

> [拜] [~~~~~] [所赐] = [thanks to][~~~~~](that made it so)
>
> [拜][在俄做生意的中国有钱人][所赐]

[拜] [~~~~~] [所赐] could be a genuine expression of thankfulness: "thanks to ~~~~~~ that made it so"

or a sarcastic remark "all because of ~~~~~ (which caused it so)"

*To [拜]  a god is to thanks him for his blessing or granted wish*

Answer (score 1):

Definitely a sarcastic 拜

拜在俄做生意的中國有錢人所賜，
A salute to the wealthy Chinese who do business in Russia,
他們的入境手續都不合法，
whose frontier crossings are all illegal,
所以一查就給錢，
and therefore, if investigated, pay,
一查就給錢，
pay each time,
一來二去警察都知道中國人好給錢了
gradually the (Russian) police learn, the Chinese can be milked.